# Loop through JSONObject and fill the spinner dynamically

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm using volley library on android and i have to parse this JSON and fill my spinner with some values that come from the volley response, that are nested inside a different json object.

Here the JSON:

```
{
"Count": 2,
"0": {
    "Distributore Information": {
        "id_distributore": "1",
        "NomeDistributore": "Colonnina 1",
    }
},
"1": {
    "Distributore Information": {
        "id_distributore": "2",
        "NomeDistributore": "Colonnina 2",
    }
}
}
```

Here the code that i write:

```
private void getInfoColonnina(){
    String url = "https://api.thisurlsidhiddenbutitsworknp_module_json";
    final SharedPreferences myPref = getSharedPreferences("loginPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor myPreff = myPref.edit();

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(InizioTurnoActivity.this, "CHIAMATA INFOCOLONNINA AVVENUTA CON SUCCESSO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();

                while(keys.hasNext()) {
                    String key = keys.next();
                    if (jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {

                        JSONObject infoDistributore = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Distributore Information");
                        LitriColonnina = infoDistributore.getString("litriiniziocolonna");
                        id_distributore = infoDistributore.getString("id_distributore");
                        NomeDistributore = infoDistributore.getString("NomeDistributore");
                    }
                }

                    final DistrBean distrTest = new DistrBean(NomeDistributore, id_distributore, LitriColonnina);

                    MaterialSpinner spinner = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
                    spinner.setItems(distrTest.getNomeDistributore());
                    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener<String>() {
                        @Override public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position, long id, String item) {
                            Toast.makeText(InizioTurnoActivity.this, distrTest.getIdDistributore(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            myPreff.putString("id_distributore", distrTest.getIdDistributore());
                            myPreff.commit();
                        }
                    });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

So the code should iterate and, create the object that fill the spinner but doesn't work. Ff I parse only one object and fill the spinner, it work fine and appear as well, but i really cant figured out how loop through a JSON get all the data that I need, every "id_distributore" and "NomeDistributore" any idea?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ArrayAdapter` for the `spinner` , than add your element to the `ArrayAdapter` using a `List`

So add your elements dynamically to a `List`  then after the `for loop` put that `list` in the `ArrayAdapter` finally set the `adapter` to the `spinner`

Example :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_indication, yourList); //yourList is the List your create dynamically in the for loop with the elements from the Json file
Spinner yourSpinner;
yourSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

> Helpfull :

Also you can add other elements to your spinner after that by adding those elements to the list than the adapter than use :

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

> EDIT :

Your Json file is formatted wrong , it should look like this :

```
{
    "Count": "2",
  "0": {
    "Distributore Information": {
      "id_distributore": "1",
      "NomeDistributore": "Colonnina 1"
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "Distributore Information": {
      "id_distributore": "2",
      "NomeDistributore": "Colonnina 2"
    }
  }
}
```

In your php file use :

```
echo json_encode($response); //response in array containing your fetched data
```

check your Json [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/)

Comment: The big problem here is how to loop the JSONObject? do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Nicola parsing Json is another question mate , provide your PHP file , ie : how are generating that file ?

Comment: I didnt work on the backend-side and i cant change the response,

Comment: @Nicola parsing Json is not a big deal , you can do it manually or with the help of 3rd party Libraries but you should contact your backend provider for this issue